# Regular expression to separate the Source path, target path, file name and other fields from a single string

Tags: regex

I need a help to write a regular expression to separate the Source path, target path, file name and other fields from a single string. My input string will be like below,

\\hostname.abcd.com\e$\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB
   E:\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB get_file_name_csv_sqldb.ktr null
   null

From this string i need below separate 5 strings,

1. \\hostname.abcd.com\e$\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB
2. E:\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB
3. get_file_name_csv_sqldb.ktr
4. null
5. null

Write now i am using [\s+] regex but if there is space in folder name it return me wrong value.

Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: How can you dertermine yourself that get_file_name_csv_sqldb.ktr is not in the 2nd part? Coz "." (dot) can be included in file path as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I'm going to give makes a few assumptions.

- The first two entries may contain spaces but the other tree must not.
- The second entry is an absolute Windows path (starting with a drive label).

If this is the case, then reverse the input string and apply this pattern:

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+([^:]+:\S)\s+(\S.+)
```

Then take the values of each group and reverse them. Groups 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 now represent the values of parts 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. The reason you need to reverse the string is so the pattern does not need to perform any backtracking.

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried the suggested regular expression with reversing the string but not getting result. Given string "null null get_file_name_csv_sqldb.ktr null E:\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB \\hostname.abcd.com\e$\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB"  and used regex "(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+([^:]+:\S)\s+(\S.+)". your assumptions are correct.

Comment: I came up with one regular expression which gives me two groups without reverse of string - "(\S.+)\s+([^:]+:\S.+)" . First group is "\\hostname.abcd.com\e$\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB" and second group is "E:\abc\Shared Transformations\CSVtoSQL\SQLDB get_file_name_csv_sqldb.ktr null null". Now not able to make 3rd, 4th and 5th group. Please suggest.